# Outlook 2010 doesn't show HTML emails sent with multipart/related

Tags: image, debugging, html-email, outlook-2010, multipart

I'm programming an email newsletter with a couple of embedded images. The headers look like:

```
... (snip)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/related;
boundary="xyzzy1220091"

This message is in MIME format. Since your mail reader does not understand
this format, some or all of this message may not be legible.

--xyzzy1220091
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1; name="tempE924AAC7.html"
Content-description: html
Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit
Content-disposition: INLINE

(HTML newsletter here)

--xyzzy1220091
Content-type: image/jpeg; name="cabecera.jpg"
Content-description: cabecera
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
Content-disposition: inline; filename="cabecera.jpg";
Content-ID: <cabecera>
```

This works correctly in Gmail, Hotmail, Apple Mail... everything I tested it on, except Outlook 2010. In it, it will show an empty message and the HTML and JPG files as attachments in separate tabs; if you click on the HTML, it will show you a preview button with a warning about showing previews only from trusted sources.

If I send the newsletter not as a multipart/related attachment, but just as a HTML email:

```
Content-type: text/html
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
```

Then it displays perfectly in Outlook... but of course, then I can't add inline images.

Comment: Embedded images are not very good cross client, see here for my source -> http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1759/embedding-images-revisited/

Wouldn't it be better to host the images online and use an absolute reference to them?

Comment: In my tests, most email clients will block images if they are hosted elsewhere; OTOH, if you embed them in the email, almost all clients will show them.

Comment: As for the original problem, I solved it by using "multipart/alternative" and not attaching the HTML part as a file.

Comment: Post your solution so that others can learn, please.

Answer (score 1):

> As for the original problem, I solved it by using "multipart/alternative" and not attaching the HTML part as a file

Comment: what do you mean ` not attaching the HTML part as a file`?